# Php get last part of url and remove /

Tags: php, angularjs

Im using an angular script for my site.

I need dynamic titles so I decided to use php to fetch the last part of the url to display for the page title.

This is the code im using. This code is out putting my full url.

```
<?php

function curPageURL() {
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_array = explode('/',$link);
$lastPart = array_pop($url);

return $lastPart;
}

echo curPageURL();
?>
```

The problem is its fetching the whole url.

For example here is my url http://www.istreamradio.ie/category/Music

I need to display just the last part of the url in this case is Music.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use end() function after exploding the URL . Please try end instead of array_pop.

Comment: can you give me an example please please please

Comment: Replace this code $lastPart = array_pop($url); with $lastPart = end($url);

Comment: <?php

function curPageURL() {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url_array = explode('/',$url);
    $lastPart = end($url);

    return $lastPart;
}

echo curPageURL();


?>

Comment: Sorry use this. $url_array = explode('/',$link);
$lastPart = end($url_array);return $lastPart;